# Elements of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{i\geq 0}\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ vanish on almost all elements of "standard basis" $\mathbb{e}_{n}$

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, projective-module, free-modules

I've been struggling with the following exerciese:

> Let $f\in\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{i\geq 0}\mathbb{Z},
> > \mathbb{Z})$, where $\prod_{i\geq 0}\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the
> $\mathbb{Z}$-module of integral sequences. For $n\geq 0$, set
> $\mathbb{e}_{n} := (0, \ldots, 0, \underbrace{1}_{n^{\mathrm{th}}\mathrm{-entry}}, 0, \ldots)$.
> Show that $f(\mathbb{e}_{n}) \neq 0$ only for finitely many
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and that if $f(\mathbb{e}_{n}) = 0$ for all
> $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $f = 0$.

That those statements are true becomes obvious in light of the fact that $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{i\geq 0}\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ is a free module. However, I'm looking for an easy and direct proof, which would work without showing freeness of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(\prod_{i\geq 0}\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: If for all $n$, $f(e_n)=0$, then show that every sequence of the form $(p^na_n)_n$ (where $p$ is a prime number and the $a_n$ are integers) is in the kernel of $f$. Then show that $f=0$ by Bezout. Not quite sure yet about the other result.

Comment: The other statement is false if $D=\mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is free.  Indeed, $D$ is uncountable, so if it were free, it would have an uncountable basis, therefore $\mathrm{Hom}(D,\mathbb{Z})$ would be uncountable. But the full problem states that $\mathrm{Hom}(D,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow S$ is injective, where $S$ is the set of sequences of integers that are zero almost everywhere (so is countable).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where does this exercise come from?